# Create sub-array list from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList such as this one

```
ArrayList<String> listed = new ArrayList<>();

listed.add("sun, water, autumn");
listed.add("moon, wind, winter");
listed.add("venus, fire, summer");
```

and I would like to create three separate ArrayList so that first one contains

```
("sun, moon, venus")
```

second one

```
("water, wind, fire")
```

and last

```
("autumn, winter, summer")
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks you all for your very useful help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    ArrayList<String> listed = new ArrayList<>();
    listed.add("sun, water, autumn");
    listed.add("moon, wind, winter");
    listed.add("venus, fire, summer");
    List<String> subList1=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> subList2=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> subList3=new ArrayList<>();
    for(String i:listed){
         subList1.add(i.split(",")[0]);
         subList2.add(i.split(",")[1]);
         subList3.add(i.split(",")[2]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Fixed format

```
    List<String> list1 =  Arrays.asList(listed.get(0).split(",")); 
    List<String> list2 =  Arrays.asList(listed.get(1).split(",")); 
    List<String> list3 =  Arrays.asList(listed.get(2).split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList finalList  = new ArrayList();
for(String s : listed) {
    finalList.add(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));  
}
```

Comment: When posting answers, it is really a great thing to explain the code that you are posting. Even if it works perfectly and it is tested, adding the explanation of WHY it works is a great thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh for your valuable comment. I will ensure this going forward.